# combining anonymous functions in perl

Tags: perl

```
my $anon1 = sub { return ( $n < 10 ? 0 : 2 ) }; # where $n is any numeric value say
my $anon2 = sub { return ( 1 ) };

my $anon3 = $anon1;
print ref($anon3)."\n";
```

Answer = 'CODE', i.e. assigning to another variable works.

Question: what is the syntax to create an anonymous function from 2 anonymous functions?

```
$anon3 = $anon1 || $anon2; # N.B. not expecting this to work but is to suggest that want a function that if $anon1 is 0 then assign to $anon2
```

N.B. I don't want to do &$anon1 || &$anon2.  I am trying to create a function which is a combination of $anon1 and $anon2.  The functions are not static.

If I could enhance the question a little further : if the number of ANON functions is variable, e.g. stored in a hash table, how could anon3 be formed dynamically as a function of the keys?

```
%anon = (
    'anon1' => sub { return ( $n < 10 ? 1 : 0 ) },
    'anon2' => sub { return ( $n < 20 ? 2 : 0 ) },
#and this may extend to N entries
    'anonN' => sub { return ( 999 ) },
); # the anonymous functions anonX are purely for example.
```

So aiming to create the following by iterating over 'sort keys %anon' :

```
$anon3 = sub { $anon{'anon1'}->() || $anon{'anon2'}->() || $anon{'anonN'}->() };
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a new anonymous function that calls both of the functions you want to combine, e.g.

```
my $anon3 = sub { $anon1->() || $anon2->() };
```

Comment: I've enhanced the original question to ask how to generate the answer programatically.